# Read value from Excel into parameter. Parameters are linked to delay block. Error Excel file can not be resolved

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to read values from excel file into different parameters created as flow chart block. Error excelFile cannot be resolved. Steps I have done to import excel:

1- created new experiment.
2- From pallet connectivity imported excel file saved in the same file as model.
3- In experiment window, opened Java action, before each experiment window typed the following code "excelFile.readFile();"
4- into parameter block, Action, on enter delay, typed the following "excelFile.getCellNumericValue("sheet1",5)"

Please see picture for more info
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "excelFile" object lives on the "Simulation" object, your process blocks are on "Main".

Please learn about object-oriented structures and read the AL help on understanding this: "[Where am I and how do I get to...](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fcode%2FAccess.html&resultof=%22%77%68%65%72%65%22%20%22%61%6D%22%20%22%69%22%20)"

In your case, best move the ExcelFile object to Main and access it from there, probably no reason to have it on "Simulation", right?

Also, consider not using ExcelFile at all. Instead, read your excel data into the build-in database and load your params from there. This is how it *should* be done ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added excel sheet into database. When I open the block diagram properties, I change the delay time to select from sheet (Object name: X, Time delay in second, 1000). I choose the table and the value column. However, each parameter has its own value. Therefore, is really important to specify the column number and row number. How can I specify the row number?

Comment: please learn how to use the database, see https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fconnectivity%2FQuery_Builder.html&resultof=%22%64%61%74%61%62%61%73%65%22%20%22%64%61%74%61%62%61%73%22%20 and other help articles. If this answer helped you, please mark it as "useful" (small up-arrow next to the reply). Helps others find answers faster in the future :)

Comment: You do not use row and column numbers but load by column name and use SQL WHERE statements. Much more powerful ;)

Comment: Hi @Dean, Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)